# How to fix Qt Visual Studio Tools "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, mfc

When converting Visual Studio MFC project to Qt VS tools project, using [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123), Visual studio throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, and the project is not converted.
Steps to reproduce the problem.

1. Install Visual studio 2017
2. Install Qt, and Qt VS Tools Visual Studio extension.
3. Create an MFC project.
4. Convert it to Qt VS Tools Project.

Converting to Qt VS Tools project detailed steps.

1. Open .vcxproj file of the project.
2. Change `"<Keyword>MFCProj</Keyword>"` under property tag `"<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">"` to `"Qt4VSv1.0"` (slide 12 - https://www.slideshare.net/GlobalLogicUkraine/migrating-from-mfc-to-qt)
3. Reload project
4. Right click, select `"Convert Project to Qt VS Tools Project"`, answer `"yes"`, in the confirmation dialog.

See the following pic.
[image: steps to reproduce]

Looking in Microsoft forums I realised that this error shows up in a lot of different situations, and has a different workaround/fix for each. 
Many of them have been addressed in different VS releases.
I didn't find anything for the Qt extension in question.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to set Qt version in the extensions configuration dialog.
"Qt VS Tools" -> "Qt Options" -> "Qt Versions" tab -> "Add"
Browse and locate the QT installation directory on your system.

See the following pic.

[image: solution]

The issue will no longer occur, and the conversion of project will go through.
Following pic shows the change this project conversion step does to project file.

[image: diff]